# In Python 3.8, How can I load a list of images from JsonStore files?

Tags: python, json, kivy, kivymd

Can I ask how can I load a list of images accordingly in MDCard from json file?
My json file at least have 20 image link inside.

***.py***

```
    def load_image(self):
        store = JsonStore('image.json')
        image = store['PRD'].get('td01')
        return image

    def build(self):
        store = JsonStore('image.json')
        return Builder.load_file('main1.kv')
```

***.kv***

```
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Toolbar:
            title: "Testing"

        Scroll:
            TLayout:
                TLayout2:
                    Card:
                        AsyncImage:
                            source: app.load_image()

                    Card:
                        AsyncImage:
                            source: app.load_image()

                    Card:
                        AsyncImage:
                            source: app.load_image()
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can easily get link of images from python but the problem is in adding them to .kv file. So, what you can do is give an `id` to the layout on which you want to add the card

```
Screen:
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Toolbar:
        title: "Testing"

    Scroll:
        TLayout:
            TLayout2:
                id: layout_2
```

(I assumed layout_2 in the example) then you can add async image and MDCard using python.

Here's an example:

```
card = MDCard(orientation='vertical', pos_hint={"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.65}, size_hint=(0.5,0.5))
img = AsyncImage(source='link_of_image', pos_hint={"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}, allow_stretch=True)
card.add_widget(img)
self.root.ids.layout_2.add_widget(card)
```

Comment: Ya you have to provide size_hint = (None, None), size = ("..", "..")

Comment: One more question I want to ask, if I using for loop to create 20 MDCard, how can I make those 20 MDCard on_release switch different screen?

Comment: Yes, you can. you can define different on_release function. In python you have to use lambda to define function. So you can do like on_release: lambda x: do_this() and if you are providing any parameter to do_this() which is chanding with loop (like i) the you have to use another variable y in lambda like this: for i in something: .... lambda x, y=i: do_this(y)

Comment: Hi, can I ask how to create a function to load a list of image from json file? The question is almost the same, but is like using the function to a list of load image for kv file instead of ```add_widget```

Comment: I didn't quite get your question. Do you mean you want to use just the kv file and load images from there without using the python code? If so then you can add but you have to make different widgets in your kv file. As far as I know, there's no such thing like a loop inside kivy so you have to make different widgets for each one and it will just make your code lengthy. And if you want to make just one widget and use different image sources using a function or any parameter then yes you can do that too but it will replace the previous one. I hope this helps